# Como parar de emitir particulas após uns segundos?

Tags: unity3d

Tenho um código simples que spawna partículas quando o player fica parado na trigger. Porém elas não param de ser emitidas e eu gostaria que elas parassem logo após uns segundos. Como posso fazer isso?

```
if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player" && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            PlayerManager.health += 1;
            MyParticleEffect.SetActive(true);

        yield WaitForSeconds(5); // wait for 5 seconds
        MyParticleEffect.SetActive(false); // turn the particle system on

            Debug.Log("e key was pressed");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro, acho que o "yield" não funciona em um Void, mas sim em um IEnumerator.
Creio que esteja usando o OnTriggerStay. Para isso,a forma fácil seria criar uma variável que conta o tempo e usar Update().

```
public class scriptest : MonoBehaviour {
   float timer = 0; //variável do tempo.
   public GameObject MyParticleEffect;//GameObject do Efeito

 void Update()
 {
    timer += Time.deltaTime; //Somando o timeDelta, conta-se o tempo.
    if (timer > 5) //Se o tempo for maior do que 5, o GameObject do efeito é desativado.
     {
        MyParticleEffect.SetActive(false);
     }
 }

 void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
 {
     if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player" && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
     {
        //Aqui vai o PlayerManager.health += 1.
        MyParticleEffect.SetActive(true); //GameObject do efeito é ativado.
        timer = 0; //Tempo é zerado.
     }
 }
}
```

Veja,também, se não tem algum script impedindo o Efeito de ser desativado.